# bad operand type String for unary operator '+++'

Tags: java

This is an assignment I am working on.

I get, bad operand type String for unary operator '+++' on line 12.

I am not sure how to fix this. I actually just copied it straight from my book... which means I spent 150$ for poor quality. but that is neither here or there. Please help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ComputeTax {

public static void main(String[] args) {
// Create a Scanner
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

// Prompt the user to enter filing status
System.out.print(
    "(0-single filer, 1-married jointly or qualifying widow(er)",
    + "\n2-married separately, 3-head of household)\n" +
    "Enter the filing status: ");
int status = input.nextInt();

// Prompt the user to enter taxable income
System.out.print("Enter the taxable income: ");
double income = input.nextDouble();

// Compute tax
double tax = 0;

if (status == 0) {// Compute tax for single filers
    if (income <= 8350)
          tax = income * 0.10;
    else if (income <= 33950)
          tax = 8350 * 0.10 + (income - 8350) * 0.15;
    else if (income <= 82250)
          tax = 8350 * 0.10 + (33950 - 8350) * 0.15 +
         (income - 33950) * 0.25;
    else if (income <= 171550)
          tax = 8350 * 0.10 + (33950 - 8350) * 0.15 +
         (82250 - 33950) * 0.25 + (income - 82250) * 0.28;
    else if (income <= 372950)
          tax = 8350 * 0.10 + (33950 - 8350) * 0.15 +
          (82250 - 33950) * 0.25 + (171550 - 82250) * 0.28 +
          (income - 171550) * 0.33;
    else
          tax = 8350 * 0.10 + (33950 - 8350) * 0.15 +
         (82250 - 33950) * 0.25 + (171550 - 82250) * 0.28 +
         (372950 - 171550) * 0.33 + (income - 372950) * 0.35;
}
else if (status == 1) {
// Left as exercise
// Compute tax for married file jointly or qualifying widow(er)
}
else if (status == 2) {
// Compute tax for married separately
// Left as exercise
}
else if (status == 3) {
// Compute tax for head of household
// Left as exercise
}
else {
    System.out.println("Error: invalid status");
    System.exit(1);
}
// Display the result
System.out.println("Tax is " + (int)(tax * 100) / 100.0);

}
```

}

Comment: I think your book is just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

remove `,` and it will work fine

```
System.out.print(
        "(0-single filer, 1-married jointly or qualifying widow(er)"
    + "\n2-married separately, 3-head of household)\n" +
    "Enter the filing status: ");
```

Answer (score 4):

```
   "(0-single filer, 1-married jointly or qualifying widow(er)",
                                                               ^---stray comma 
   + "\n2-married separately, 3-head of household)\n" +
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra comma.

```
"widow(er)",
```